# trying to print arrays in java

Tags: java, arrays

I had a code I needed to submit and every time I try to run it, I get the same errors over and over again.

Here's the question

> Write the following Java methods:
>
> (a). readValues to input ten integer values into an array of integers
> TAB from a text file “Values.txt”. This array TAB is passed to the
> method as parameter. Assume that the number of students in the file is
> equal to the length of the array.
>
> (b).  oddValues that takes the array TAB as parameter and returns the
> number of odd values found in TAB.
>
> (c). replaceOdd that takes the array TAB as a parameter. It should
> replace every odd value in TAB by the sum of all odd values.
>
> Hint: your method must first compute the sum of all odd values.
>
> (d).  printValues that takes the array TAB as a parameter and prints
> its content on the screen.
>
> (e). main that declares the array TAB and calls the above four
> methods.
>
> N.B.: In your program, use the methods and variable names as mentioned
> above.

And this is the code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Finalexam
{
    public static void main (String [] args ) throws FileNotFoundException 
{
    int sum=0;
    int [] TAB=new int [10];
    ReadValues(TAB);
    oddValues(TAB);
    replaceOdd(TAB);
    printValues(TAB);

    System.out.println("The sum is" + sum);

}
public static void ReadValues (int [] TAB)
{
 {   int i;
    for(i=0; i<10; i++){
     Scanner s = new Scanner ("Values.txt") ;
     TAB[i]=s.nextInt();
    }
}
    s.close();
}
public static double oddValues(int[] TAB)
{
    int i;
    double odd=0;
    int fn=0;
    for(i=1; i<odd; i++){

    
    while(odd % 2 !=0)
        {
            odd = fn;
        }
        break;
    }
    return fn;
}

public static int replaceOdd(int[] TAB)
{
    int re=0;
    for(int i=0; i<TAB.length; i++){
        re = re/TAB.length;
    }
    return re;
}
public static void printValues(int[] TAB)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<10; i++){
        System.out.println(TAB[i]+"\t");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
}
```

In which part I'm doing wrong? I cant even run it.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add the errors that you are getting to the question.

Comment: There seems to be multiple errors. For example s is not defined. Also in method ReadValues there seems to be unnecessary { }. I think you should separate the errors and ask them separately.

Comment: In ReadValues method you have compilation issue. Declare scanner outside for-loop.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly there is a compilation error in your code.

In your method

```
public static void ReadValues (int [] TAB)
    {
        {   int i;
            for(i=0; i<10; i++){
                Scanner s = new Scanner ("Values.txt") ;
                TAB[i]=s.nextInt();
            }
        }
        s.close();
    }
```

You have too many extra brackets, well thats not the problem though, the problem is the scanner object s is declared inside the for loop where as you are closing it later outside the loop, since the scope of the variable is not outside the loop, hence the error.
The correct way should be

```
public static void readValues (int [] tab){
        int i;
        Scanner s = new Scanner ("Values.txt") ;
        for(i=0; i<10; i++){
                tab[i]=s.nextInt();
        }
        s.close();
}
```

Also there are many thing that will work in your code but is a bad practice or is not following conventions.

1. Variable names (e.g tab) should always be in camel case. It should only be a capital if it is a constant, which is not in your case.
2. The method names starts with small letter.
3. Also you are calling the two methods `replaceOdd(TAB)` and `oddValues(TAB)` But the return value is not being used anywhere.
4. FileNotFoundException will never be thrown

If you closely look at this method below

```
public static double oddValues(int[] TAB) {
    int i;
    double odd = 0;
    int fn = 0;
    for (i = 1; i < odd; i++) {

        while (odd % 2 != 0) {
            odd = fn;
        }
        break;
    }
    return fn;
}
```

The loop will never execute as `odd` is `0` so i<odd will always be false. Also the logic for odd is wrong.

```
public static int replaceOdd(int[] TAB){
    int re=0;
    for(int i=0; i<TAB.length; i++){
        re = re/TAB.length;
    }
    return re;
}
```

This method will always return zero, the logic is wrong.

There are many more logical errors. I would suggest you to look into them as well